# Невозможно удалить базу данных почтовых ящиков

Tags: exchange

Обновляем сервер Exchange с 2003 до 2010. Первый раз когда ставил сервер 2010, поставил неудачно, потом вручную удалял его. Второй раз поставился, но теперь в управлении базами данных висит база с неудачного сервера и при попытке удалить пишет Невозможно удалить базу данных почтовых ящиков